# Change width of HTML <form> using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have an input field surrounded by a form in a navbar and I would like to reduce the size of the form to about 75% of the width of the container it is currently inside.

When there is no `<form></form>`, the input is exactly 75% the size of the container it's in and it looks perfect.

Incomplete Navbar HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container" id="home">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="input-group md-form form-sm form-2 pl-0" id="search" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name ="search" id ="search" placeholder="Search Users" aria-label="Search" class="form-control my-0 py-1">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="navbarButton"><i class="fas fa-search text-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="submit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
```

CSS code I tried:

```
#search {
    max-width: 75%;
}

form {
    width: 75%;
}
```

The form does not change size and remains the same size regardless of the screen width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks fine to me:

```css
.container{
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
}

#search {
    max-width: 75%;
}

form {
    width: 75%;
  background: gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">
        <div class="container" id="home">
            <form method="post">
                <div class="input-group md-form form-sm form-2 pl-0" id="search" method="post">
                    <input type="text" name ="search" id ="search" placeholder="Search Users" aria-label="Search" class="form-control my-0 py-1">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="submit" id="navbarButton"><i class="fas fa-search text-grey" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="submit" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working for me. Could it possibly be because I'm using Bootstrap 4?

Comment: @Nate Yes, that could be it. Temporarily disable it and see what happens. You may be able to override it by giving your style rules `important!` declarations.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Turns out it's a lot of spaghetti Bootstrap code mixed in with what I was doing. I added the ```<form></form>``` tags without double checking what I was doing and whether it follows Bootstrap's rules. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean:

Change

```
container
```

to

```
container-fluid
```